# How to implement this list with listview.builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-list-tile

I am using an API endpoint where I am getting following type of List in:

```json
[
 [
    { "productName": "Chicken Biryani Half" },
    { "productName": " Chicken Momos" }

 ],
 [
    { "productName": "Chicken Biryani Half" },
    { "productName": "Chicken Biryani Half" },
    { "productName": " Chicken Momos" }
 ]
]
```

How do I implement this with `Listview.builder`?

Comment: What's the significance of the separate lists?  Is there some meta information missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

OUTPUT:

[image]

CODE:

```
class MyListViewBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<List<Map<String, String>>> data = [
    [
      {"productName": "Chicken Biryani Half"},
      {"productName": "Chicken Momos"}
    ],
    [
      {"productName": "Chicken Biryani Half"},
      {"productName": "Chicken Biryani Half"},
      {"productName": "Chicken Momos"}
    ]
  ];

  MyListViewBuilder({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text("Example"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Group ${index + 1}',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: data[index].length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int subIndex) {
                  final product = data[index][subIndex];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(product["productName"]!),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Commonly API calls will returns dynamic data, you have good knowledge handle API response, but don't use without formats because our code should be more readability for othres, I appreciate your help to others.

Comment: You can pass data using the required parameter on the above screen. If you require any assistance, please feel free to inform me.Thanks @K.D.Dilshan

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

In this cause you should make model class for manage our API response data, and you should keep your mind we cannot access dynamic data with listView builder we want use Future builder with random data like API call,

**1.First we should make our model class like bellow,**

```
class Product {
  final String productName;

  Product({required this.productName});

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
      productName: json['productName'],
    );
  }
}
```

**2.Look at bellow API data fetch part,**

```
 Future<List<Product>> fetchProducts() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('YOUR_API_ENDPOINT'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server returns a 200 OK response, parse the JSON
      List<dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      List<Product> productList = [];
      for (dynamic data in responseData) {
        productList.add(Product.fromJson(data));
      }
      return productList;
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load products');
    }
  }
```

you should learn asynchronous programming know about async and wait keywords, read flutter documentation get more details you can read it using [this](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

**3.Now we can pass our data into list, like bellow.**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
      future: fetchProducts(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data![index].productName),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

- `fetchProducts()` makes an HTTP GET request to your API endpoint.
  Replace `'YOUR_API_ENDPOINT'` with the actual URL of your API
  endpoint.
- If the request is successful (status code 200), it parses the JSON
  response and creates a list of `Product` objects.
  If an error occurs during the request or parsing, it throws an    exception which is caught by the `FutureBuilder` and displayed as an
  error message.

in this implementation will be help fix your issue, and I attach new link for learn fetch data from internet, use this [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) for read it.